Starting Nekoray with sudo
I need the GUI proxy manager Nekoray to always start in sudo mode, so that I don’t need to enter the sudo password multiple times when using the program.
(I know this can be done in the terminal, but it is inconvenient, plus I would need to keep the respective terminal window open.)

Is this possible in Fedora 40 Gnome?

If it isn’t possible, how do I at least run Nekoray with sudo privileges at system start-up? I was advised to create a systemctl service, but this did not work, as explained here. I tried creating a crontab job too, but Nekoray simply would not run.



I must admit I don't know nekoray, but: Proxy settings are something that each user sets for themselves. Why does a proxy manager need to run as root?

From this discussion, it seems that starting vpn needs sudo rights as prerequisite... https://github.com/MatsuriDayo/nekoray/issues/208

but… that's not right. On modern systems, you can set up a VPN connection as normal user. I don't know what nekoray does, but becoming root / using sudo is unnecessary. Is there a specific reason you need to use nekoray instead of just setting up your VPN connection in your network manager?

On the virtual server side, I have Outline installed. It uses Shadowsocks protocol. My guess is that the system's network manager won't interact with it.

uh, but for a shadowsocks VPN you doubly don't need root? That's just a program that runs as your user, and acts as a SOCKS5 proxy, and that's it. There's not even a virtual network interface that needs to be created.

I have serious security doubts about it being wise to install a Chinese-language VPN frontend and run it as root, if it doesn't even need root to function. This feels like such an obvious goal for government backdooring: The Chinese government doesn't entertain such extensive censoring infrastructure to be circumvented by everyone using shadowsocks. The most intuitive way to know what people that are circumventing are doing is backdooring a VPN client.

But it's open source... Anyway, do you think there is another way of using Shadowsocks as a client? I tried Outline Client first, but it is buggy and does not really work in Fedora. I've fund multiple bug reports describing the same problems I faced.

there's the "official" go client

What is a "go" client? Go is a programming language, isn't it?

the original shadowsocks implementation was and still is written and maintained in Go

Thanks! But the Linux version is discontinued: https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-qt5/wiki/Installation

After some trials and errors, I chose Hiddify for both Android and Linux. The Linux client does not request the sudo password. https://github.com/hiddify/hiddify-next Thanks for the help, Marcus.

Wish I could have helped you more! But very glad you found a way!

After the comments by Marcus Müller, I did some trials and errors and finally chose Hiddify for both Android and Linux. The Linux client does not require the sudo password.
